# Why does Hungary mix politics with children's education?

Tags: education, hungary

According to [this article](http://hungarianspectrum.org/2017/01/06/teaching-and-politics-a-grade-eight-geography-book/) (one of) the grade 8 geography textbook shows several pictures there are clearly biased against EU and US:

> Then there is an incredible illustration in the grade 8 geography
>   textbook. It depicts Germany as a sow, feeding four little piglets
>   that represent countries that are dependent on Germany’s financial
>   help: Greece, Spain, Portugal, and Belgium. A fifth piggy, identified
>   by a Hungarian flag, stands aside, giving the impression that Hungary
>   is not the beneficiary of money that Germany pays into the common
>   purse of the European Union.

Clearly this is related to current political climate surrounding Hungary and EU. However, it is unclear why let such political issues invade school textbooks especially for children that will not be able to vote in the next EU elections.

**Question:** Why does Hungary mix politics with children's education?

Comment: All social sciences are unavoidably politicised.

Comment: @SamuelRussell, but if question is about just one country, reader may decide, that this is the only example.)

Comment: @SamuelRussell It is; but not all school textbooks are government controlled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ah, how cute. The nice fat sow is nursing the even cuter little piglets in blissful loving motherhood.
All soon to be slaughtered."

Well, pictures do say more than a thousand words. And that offers a multitude of interpretations.

As this question is framed and the original source misses to give necessary context:

Almost all schoolbooks do that. In America they include intelligent design in biology textbooks. In many countries they have a famous picture in them that is incredibly brutal: a small boy with fear in his face and his hands up is rounded up by German soldiers and on his way to death in a concentration camp.
Then many caricatures are frequently used to teach the children how to analyse them.

In this case, perhaps: Describe the picture, analyse what is used to convey a message. What is this message? Is it true, or manipulative? –– Then I would say: "nicely done."
It can be really 'just an illustration' used to spice up a bland text about the inner workings of the EU financial politics of specific time. If used in this way to summarise the textual content, I'd say: "What *were* they thinking?"

All schoolbooks have political content, politicised content in them. Some have disgusting content or questionable content. Some may have content you disagree with.

It is a matter of context, aim and presentation.

This can be seen as necessary to teach the school children how the politicised world of mass communication works. This can be used to indoctrinate the students in certain ways. Politicised content can be good, can be egregious. But it cannot be seen as avoidable. That would make a lot of books useless. Especially those about history, sociology and other social sciences close to politics itself. Thinking of it as 'avoidable' is an illusion. And necessarily a backfiring one.

---

Notice that in this case the picture is the following:

> [image]

And the text seems to say:

> **Among the world's leading powers.**
> Of most of the people who are living in Europe, most of them are farmers. It is one of the most important policies of the European Union, the dominant role of the world economy and the world of politics.
>
> Does anyone get it? Germans pay the most into the European Union's coffers. Identify the cartoonists, then elaborate the picture.

(Mostly machine translated. And therefore dubious in its intricacies.
Hungarian speakers: Please correct if this is incorrect.
The translation is preliminary.
Do not read too much into the English version of it!)

Notice the imperfect depiction of one piglet. It's either Belgium done wrong or again Germany! A pertuum piglet.

If the translation approximates correctness, I'd say that this leaves most of the outcome to the teacher, as there seems to be no obvious solution given? Can be good, can be bad.

Comment: What?  Does Hungary really teach its children that most people living in Europe are farmers?  That's just radically wrong.

Comment: Note that, if the exercise is to train children to read critically and understand the power of imagery, including this image in a textbook is no less indoctrination than including an [Aktion T4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EuthanasiePropaganda.jpg) poster or fragments of other nazi propaganda in educational material.  It may be that there is a centralised plan to politicise Hungarian kids against the EU or other countries, or may be not, the inclusion of this image by itself does not prove that there is.

Comment: @gerrit I wouldn't put it that way. But the agriculture part is a large part of the EU budget: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_of_the_European_Union

Comment: (1) I'm not saying it *isn't* an attempt to indoctrinate children, just that it might not be; and (2) yes, agriculture is a huge part of the EU budget, but most people in Europe are not farmers.  Those are two very different statements.

Comment: @gerrit I *completely* do not disagree with you ;) But then I wouldn't bet my farm on *'my'* translation either. Unless the translation is improved, I'd say it's just a little more context with some gist put in. The translation *needs* improvement. Currently it's preliminary at best.

Comment: @gerrit  In "no less indoctrination" should that be "no more indoctrination"?  The former would claim that both this and Nazi propaganda are intended to indoctrinate.  The latter claims that neither are really intended to indoctrinate when included in class.  The latter seems to make more sense in the context of your comment, but I don't want to misread your work by putting words in your mouth.

Comment: @Brythan Yes, I mean that either can be included in history or politics textbooks and are not propaganda when properly contextualised.  Thanks.